# Mega Arduino 2560 and Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, arduino, avr-gcc, avrdude

I have an [Arduino Mega 2560](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega2560). I want to make it communicate with Eclipse in order set a program on it. I have managed to work with [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and [Arduino Pro Mini](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini) until now.

With Arduino Mega 2560, though, I get the error shown on the photo below. I have used at the programmer "Arduino" , "STK500 v2" and "v1" at 57600 and at 115200. I get the error at the photo all the time with Arduino programmer. With [STK500](http://www.atmel.com/tools/STK500.aspx), I get an error that says:

> Timeout while trying to access AVRdude programmer"

Is there a solution?

[image: PrintScreen of the Error]

Answer (score 0):

AVRdude emits a line like this:

```
avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9702
```

which identifies the device, i.e. the exact type of chip it's connected to (the above is for the ATmega128). Your plug-in is probably not aware of the particular signature emitted for the ATmega2560.

It would be nice if you had included the GUI occluded by the error dialog, where the MCU type is configured ...

Comment: I see that signature at the supported mcus but i can not find what the eclipse read from the device can you guide me where to look?

Comment: Well now i got what you ask sorry.I have setteed to Atmega2560 and 16Mhz.but this is what i have set.If i xhoose something else the test corrects it.